# Achievements dropdown not matching actual reputation since read-only time

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

I just got an upvote on a question here on meta to push my daily total reputation to +15. This is shown correctly on the reputation tab on my profile page…

> [image]

…as well as the reputation list…

> [image]

However, the achievements dropdown does not show this, preserving the +10 that I received (before the recent scheduled read-only time—possible cause?). It's also not showing the green +[rep] badge on the button.

> [image]

Also, I've got 66 reputation today on Ask Different, but it still shows 70 in the achievements dropdown, shown above. The actual list of reputation received/lost in the achievements dropdown has not updated either.

> [image]

Comment: Also noticed this, +1.

Comment: This is the same issue as the linked dupe; the notification boxes (achievements and inbox) are thoroughly børken.